# incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Matcher<T> conforms to ArgumentMatcher<Long>

Tags: java, mockito

```
private long userId = 1;
```

```
@Before
    public void before() {
        when(userStatisticsDAO.findByUserIDAndCurrency(longThat(isLessThanOrEqualTo(userId)), any(Currency.class))).thenReturn(userStatistics);
    }
```

```
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Matcher<T> isLessThanOrEqualTo(T value) {
        return OrderingComparison.lessThanOrEqualTo(value);
    }
```

Error occurs on:

`longThat(isLessThanOrEqualTo(userId)`

`incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Matcher<T> conforms to ArgumentMatcher<Long>`

Comment: Please show the parameter and method structure for `userStatisticsDAO.findByUserIDAndCurrency(...)`

Comment: `UserStatistics findByUserIDAndCurrency(long identifier, Currency currency);`

Comment: Looks like you might be mixing up Hamcrest Matcher and mockito ArgumentMatcher?

Comment: Maybe `MockitoHamcrest.longThat` would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `ArgumentMatcher` implementation to use alongside `longThat(...)`.

The `isLessThanOrEqualTo` method you created is not an `ArgumentMatcher` type that is expected by the `longThat(...)` method.

See example below

```
@Test
public void test() {
    long userId = 10;

    when(userStatisticsDAO.findByUserIDAndCurrency(
        ArgumentMatchers.longThat(new LessThanEquals(userId)), any(Currency.class)))
           .thenReturn(userStatistics);

    Assert.assertNull(userStatisticsDAO.findByUserIDAndCurrency(199, currency));
    Assert.assertNotNull(userStatisticsDAO.findByUserIDAndCurrency(1, currency));
    Assert.assertNotNull(userStatisticsDAO.findByUserIDAndCurrency(10, currency));
}

class LessThanEquals implements ArgumentMatcher<Long> {
    final long limit;

    public LessThanEquals(long limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public boolean matches(Long input) {
        return input != null && input <= limit;
    }
}

// Don't use this, since it's not returning an ArgumentMatcher
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Matcher<T> isLessThanOrEqualTo(T value) {
    return OrderingComparison.lessThanOrEqualTo(value);
}
```

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argument-matchers